# How to break the loop in an Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, break

I'm trying to write a simple program in Arduino, blinking of a LED.

Program is as shown below.

```
#define red1 13
#define amber1 12
#define green1 11

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);  
    pinMode(red1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(amber1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(green1, OUTPUT);
}

void Delay(int sec) {
    for(int i=0;i<sec;i++){
        if (Serial.available())
        {
            Button();
            break;
        }
        delay(1);
     }
}

void Light()
{
    digitalWrite(red1,HIGH);
    Delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(red1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(amber1,HIGH);
    Delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(amber1,LOW);
}

void Button()
{
    digitalWrite(red1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(amber1,LOW);      
    digitalWrite(green1,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(green1,LOW);
}

void loop() 
{
    Light();  
}
```

When ever I enter a value in serial monitor `Button()` function is executed, it should end as soon as function completes due to a break, but this function keeps repeating continuously? How can I fix this such that whenever a serial monitor is interrupted, `Button()` is executed onetime and then continues with `Light()`.

Comment: Read the byte off the serial interface so it's not still there next time around.

Comment: Your break is related to the if statement here. So it just exits the if.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois yes, I used loop() instead of break didn't work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. Your `break` exits the `if` context and not the `for` context (the context is what is inside the corresponding brackets `{...}`). The solution given by HeheBoi makes you exit the `for` context, which is what you want.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois that's wrong. Break will break the for loop as he desires, the problem isn't that.

Comment: @samuelnj Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

`break;`

with

`return;`

This will terminate the function instantly since you won't be executing other statements after the loop.

You can look at https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/return/ for more info about `return`

Comment: its still continue to on green led with less intensity blink of red and amber https://www.tinkercad.com/things/8Iq1hiD28UJ-brave-turing/editel?tenant=circuits?sharecode=zywhaJlxAkhAgMH0AfyWWpTzg1GiVNNsX-08e_NTDgM=

Comment: @deepinside What do you mean?

Comment: @deepinside By the way, you should do what Mark Setchell said.

Comment: @HeheBoi in this case, `break` and `return` do exactly the same thing functionally. It isn't the problem.

Comment: I replaced as you said, but when I interrupt serial monitor green led supposed to blink for a second but it stays on and continues with red and yellow led blink with lesser intensity

Answer (score 0):

As some others have briefly alluded to, you call `Button` many times due to the fact that you don't clear the serial interface.

Right now what happens is `Delay` is called, and let's say there's information available on the interface, then you call `Button` and `break` as expected, but since you don't clear the interface by reading the available information, you call `Button` again on the next call to `Delay`.

To fix this, you need to read the information from the serial interface either in the `Button` function or in the `if` statement before calling `Button`.

Comment: I can't read serial interface function from Button  because I want to call that function whenever I write in a serial interface, if I call in Light() then during the time of delay() serial interface couldn't be read

Comment: @deepinside you'll have to explain a bit better, I have no idea why you can't read from the serial interface...

Comment: when the delay() function is executing, Arduino is in sleep mode, so if I interrupt serial interface also it doesn't read it, so I created separate Delay()